# how to redeliver onexception in camel and call global exception if redelivery fails

Tags: apache-camel

My requirement is to redeliver message on exception, and if the redeliveries didn't workout, route the exchange to global exception and not to dead letter queue... is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `defaultErrorHandler`

```
defaultErrorHandler.maximumRedeliveries(3)
```

The above will attempt to redeliver 3 times

From the [documentation](http://camel.apache.org/defaulterrorhandler.html)

> It has the same power as the Dead Letter Channel, however it does not support a dead letter queue, which is the only difference between the two of them.